# How Can I Get Exclusive Lock On Drive / Partition Win-Api 32?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

How to lock lock on specific drive till i perform some operation(read/write) on that drive.
When i have captured lock on drive, no other process should able to write on that drive unitl I release lock on that drive, I have found one API i.e. `DeviceIoControl()`,
but I want access on drive for my process only, but the above API 'MAY' block access of all the processes. I'm not quite sure how `lockfile()` and `lockfileex()` works. Please help me find some way / API/ Logic to do this!
...
...
UPDATED :-

with referrance to your answer i have tried this :-->

```
   HANDLE hdest,hf;
   DWORD b,write;
   hdest = CreateFile("\\\\?\\E:",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    if (hdest == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("NOT OK"),TEXT("NOT OK"),0);
    }

    if (DeviceIoControl( hdest,FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,NULL,0,NULL,0,&b,NULL))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("OK"),TEXT("OK"),0);

            hf = CreateFile(TEXT("E:\\M_lucky.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
                if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("NOT OK AFTER LOCK I"),TEXT("NOT OK AFTRE LOCK"),0);
                }
            WriteFile(hf, TEXT("M very lucky"), 13, &write, NULL);
    }

    CloseHandle((HANDLE)hdest);
    CloseHandle((HANDLE)hf);

    DeviceIoControl( hdest,FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME,NULL,0,NULL,0,&b,NULL);

    hf = CreateFile(TEXT("E:\\MNOT_lucky.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
                if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("NOT OK AFTER LOCK"),TEXT("NOT OK AFTRE LOCK"),0);

                }
            WriteFile(hf, TEXT("M lucky"), 8, &write, NULL);
    CloseHandle((HANDLE)hf);
```

""but........""
after getting exclusive lock on E drive, i am unable to create file.
(i have read that : only hdest(HANDLE) gets exclusive lock on that drive. )

here..!!! i want to create M_LUCKY.txt file..!!
(I need EXLUSIVE access on drive with context to PROCESS)
plz help! thanks a lottt!!

is there any other method for doing this??

Comment: What kind of problem is with DeviceIOControl?

Comment: Do you read carefully MSDN link? Because locking volume also dismount volume, so your trying about CreateFile is useless.

Comment: so is there any other way to achieve such functionality????

Comment: Maybe describing your concrete problem to avoiding XY problem.

Comment: SIR WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY "AVOIDING XY PROBLEM"??

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DeviceIoControl with FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME control code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364575(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: please see the edited question...!!
i couldnt post in comment section cause of limitation of no. of characters...